# Faced an Issue related to Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to store data to Firebase Cloud Firestore but after running my app it showed this error in the log.

> [Firestore]: Write failed at Backpaper Registration/WSjZoirLf8WRBuGCVbUZ: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

This is the part of my code.

```
fb=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

map=new HashMap<String>();
        map.put("Name of Department",txtDepartment);
        map.put("Name of Student",txtStudentName);
        map.put("Registration No",txtRegNo);
        map.put("CGPA in Previous Semester",txtCgpa);
        map.put("Phone",txtPhoneNo);
        map.put("Email",txtEMail);
        map.put("Subject 1",txtSubject1);
        map.put("Subject 2",txtSubject2);
        map.put("Subject 3",txtSubject3);
        map.put("Subject 4",txtSubject4);
        map.put("Subject 5",txtSubject5);
        map.put("Payment Details(Rs.)",txtPaymentDetails);
        map.put("Payment Date",txtPaymentDate);

        fb.collection("Backpaper Registration").add(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(Backpaper.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Backpaper.this,Academic.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                    finish();

                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Backpaper.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you switched Firebase Database to Test Mode ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the **Rules** on Firebase

Change allow `read, write: if false; to true;`

**Nots:**

> It is not advised to choose this solution because it makes the
>   database unsafe.

**Only** use this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Firebase rules setting at Firebase console.

If you had signed into project, the rules setting may like :

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If you just demo the function, you call setting the rules:

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The more officially document you can found here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 0):

It could be because, you have not given the **read & write permission** to firebase.
Change your Firebase Database to test mode.

1. Go to your firebase database console
2. Go to Rules
3. Start in **test mode**
 
This will change `allow read, write: true` 

[image: Firestore, Start in **test mode**]
**This turn off the database security but for testing purpose it is advised**